# Programmatically identifying Ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible, yaml

Given the source code of a project, I need to identify whether it uses Ansible or not. For doing that, I thought of searching through all the YAML files in the source code hierarchy and check if those are Ansible playbooks.

Are there any tags or some structure unique to Ansible playbooks for differentiating them from other YAML files?

Or is there a better way of checking whether a project uses Ansible, just by analyzing its source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does a project need to do to qualify as a project *using ansible*? Does it need to contain a playbook? Does it need to actually call ansible? Does it suffice for the project to have some documentation regarding using the project together with ansible? The answer to your question largely depends on your answer to this question.

> Are there any tags or some structure unique to Ansible playbooks for differentiating them from other YAML files?

The simplest way of checking whether a YAML file is a valid ansible playbook is to do something like

```
ansible-playbook file.yaml --syntax-check --list-tasks
```

and check its return value. However, this is only a heuristic. There is no guarantee that someone in some project has a YAML file that happens to be a valid ansible playbook, but is used for a completely different purpose.

> Or is there a better way of checking whether a project uses Ansible, just by analyzing its source code?

Grepping for `ansible`, excluding documentation files, might be sufficient heuristic. You could of course check whether the code calls some ansible binary, but you would need to parse the code's AST, walk it and *understand it* – and even then, it would still simply be a heuristic, because you cannot be sure that someone did not name some executable like an ansible executable (not very likely though). I would say that the gain of precision compared to grepping and / or searching for playbooks does not justify the cost to develop such a check. At all.

Comment: I will go with the ansible-playbook file.yaml --syntax-check approach. In this case, we think, to qualify as a project using ansible it only needs to contain at least one valid playbook.